# How to give dynamically elements inside different divs the same height?

Tags: css

I have different outer-divs with the same dynamically content. Each outer-div consists of a header (h1), one or more div's or p's and a button. Because of the dynamically content, the height of each element inside the outer-div is not known.
What I want: the elements (h1, div, p, a) inside the outer-div have all a equal height, correspondenting to the biggest element. 
So if h1 in the second outer-div has a height of 45px, all the h1-element of the other outer-div's must have a height of 45px. If the div in the third outer-div has a height of 112px, all the divs in the other outer-divs must have a height of 112px. Etc.

Is it possible to apply that to the elements inside the outer-div via css? I know it's possible with jQuery, I prefer css.

Preferably with an example, just 'flex' doesn't seem te work :-(

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not work out that way.

you can try this:
external div's make the same height through display: flex;
inside 3 blocks

```
.items {

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
   width: 33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQyBLm

Comment: Thanx, but when i change the content of H1 to something with more characters (ex 20 times 'h1'), than the other H1-tags don't get the right height.

Comment: so it does not work without js
this is an option how to do alignment